# Проверка на вхождение в группу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть 4 переменные и вводимая цифра, каждая из цифр вводится с отдельной строки:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
```

Как сделать проверку на то, будет ли третий и четвёртый человек в одной группе? (a это сколько всего человек, b это по сколько человек отправляется в группу c, то есть например b = 2, значит сначала 2 человека отправляются в группу c, затем следующие 2 человека отправляются в группу d)

(Ну вот например вы вводим первым число 9, дальше второе число 3 (первые 3 человека идут в одну группу, следующие люди идут во вторую группу (группы всего 2), дальше заново, следующие идут снова в первую и следующие идут снова во вторую) И нужно понять окажется ли например Миша (Переменная c, с это также его номер) в одной с группе с например Сашей (переменная d, также его номер) Пример: 9 3 1 6 Вывод: NO)

Ограничение `a <= 10**9`

Была идея сделать с кратностью, что-то вроде:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
if a <= 10**9:
    if a % b == 0:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Но это бред какой-то

Comment: Напишите пример подробнее, так очень тяжело понять условие задачи.

Comment: Ну вот например вы вводим первым число 9, дальше второе число 3 (первые 3 человека идут в одну группу, следующие люди идут во вторую группу (группы всего 2), дальше заново, следующие идут снова в первую и следующие идут снова во вторую)
И нужно понять окажется ли например Миша (Переменная c, с это также его номер) в одной с группе с например Сашей (переменная d, также его номер)
Пример:
9
3
1
6
Вывод:
NO

Comment: так понятнее, только вы это в условие добавьте, а не в комментарии

Comment: Хорошо, исправил

Comment: Это задача на целочисленное деление

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (((c-1)//b)%2)==(((d-1)//b)%2):
```